# When I try to make an array in Ruby from a file, it makes multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

sorry if this is a simple solution, but I'm trying to grab all the numbers from a file into an array. The file I'm importing reads

```
3 5 10 
2 7 15
```

This is my code

```
grab = Array.new
IO.foreach("test.txt") do |line|
  grab = line.chomp(" " + "/n").split
end
p grab
```

When I do this, it prints the last line of numbers, yet when I print it from the IO block, it prints 2 arrays. First and second line.

Comment: *grab = line.chomp(" " + "/n").split* you put an array in grab 2 times, split returns an array... what do you expect to have?

Comment: It's unclear whether you consider the file to contain a single array (vector) split across two lines, or a 2-d array (matrix).  Please clarify?

Comment: The problem is that you're not adding items to the array (as you might with `grab << line...` or `grab.push(line...)`, you're replacing the array entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consolidate this into a singular array:

```
grab = [ ]

IO.foreach("test.txt") do |line|
  grab.concat(line.chomp.split)
end
```

Another way:

```
grab = IO.readlines("test.txt").flat_map do |line|
  line.chomp.split
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like

```
grab << line.chomp(" " + "/n").split
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you what you're looking for:

```
grab = IO.foreach("test2.txt").map {|line| line.split(/\D/) }.flatten
puts "#{grab}"
```

This produces the single array output:

```
["3", "5", "10", "2", "7", "15"]
```

It can all be wrapped up into a nice, tidy one-liner if you prefer it that way:

```
grab = IO.foreach("test2.txt").map {|line| line.split(/\D/) }.flatten
puts "#{grab}"
```

If you want to do an integer conversion in the process, you can modify the `line.split` to this:

```
grab = line.split(/\D/).map(&:to_i)
```

That change will produce this output:

```
[3, 5, 10, 2, 7, 15]
```